# Cannot update user profile specially photo in firebase android

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, user-profile

I am trying to update my user profile (specifically the photo) by making intent for choosepicker to select image from my gallery and upload it to my firebase authenticated storage.  It's working almost fine:  pics are getting uploaded to the path I describe.

The problem is I cannot retreive it back as I want.  I want to update user profile pic and use `UpdateProfileRequest` but it's just not updating anything, nor can I retrieve anything.

Here's the code:

```
final ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoURI);

        if (photoUri == null) {
            photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.user);
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"DP is Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            photo.setImageURI(photoUri);
        }

        Button editPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit_photo);
        editPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
            }
        });
```

Here is my activity result code

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        final Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

        // Get a reference to store file at User_photos/<FILENAME>
        StorageReference photoRef = storageReference.child(userID).child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

        // Upload file to firebase Storage
        photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                String imageUrl = downloadUrl.toString();
                User user = new User(imageUrl);
                databaseReferencenew.child(userID).child("Profile_Pic_URL").setValue(user);
                FirebaseUser user2 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                        .setDisplayName(mName)
                        .setPhotoUri(selectedImageUri)
                        .build();

                user2.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"User profile updated.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it show if you log the string value of selectedImageUri?

Comment: I am new to android i dont know how to log values can you tell me please it will be a grwt help. Also i dont know how but code started working next day when i signed out the account and logged in with new one

Comment: The only problem left now is the pic is not shown in the imageview immediately when i update new one from old one.It shows after i sign out and sign in again.